# Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7 - Process concurrent POST requests in parallel

Tags: multithreading, apache

I have `httpd server` running on `Centos7`. The apache details - `Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16`

I've configured the below for multi threaded behavior

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    ServerLimit         300
    MaxClients          300
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

From the front end, I can see that, once the user clicks "submit" button, 30 ajax POST calls are made in parallel & are waiting for response. Each of these ajax calls are meant to run a SQL on the DB. The SQL query execution time on the DB once the query hits the DB is very less.

Though there are 30 AJAX requests fired in parallel, the Apache server doesn't seem to fire them all off to the DB at the same time for some reason.

Is there any configuration that needs to be enabled on apache to do this?

I've tried to explain what I've observed. Please let me know if my question could be worded better please. I'll do my best.

I look forward to some guidance here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apache server doesn't seem to fire them all off to the DB

Apache does not do that. It just handles the request and gives it to resource that is requested by client. It is your script/program that is requested that connect to DB.

> The SQL query execution time on the DB once the query hits the DB is very less.

If your 30 AJAX queries running in parallel almost at the same time and they are all same, I believe DB server will cache its result and just returns cached result.